# I cant Run the Gem Annotate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Working in Codeanywhere I update the Gem file with `# Annotate models
gem 'annotate'` and later using `bundle update` I saw in the gems:

```
Instaling annotate....
```

The problem is when I use `$ annotate` i get this error code

```
/home/cabox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `load': /home/cabox/workspace/blog/app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:72: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBE
G or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END (SyntaxError)                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :, :body)                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                         ^                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    from /home/cabox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `block in load_file'                                                                                                                
    from /home/cabox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:633:in `new_constants_in'                                                                                                                  
    from /home/cabox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:442:in `load_file'                                                                                                                         
    from /home/cabox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `require_or_load'                                                                                                                   
    from /home/cabox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:307:in `depend_on'                                                                                                                         
    from /home/cabox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'                                                                                                                
    from /home/cabox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:468:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'                                                                                                                       
    from /home/cabox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:467:in `each'                                                                                                                                                  
    from /home/cabox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:467:in `block in eager_load!'                                                                                                                                  
    from /home/cabox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `each'                                                                                                                                                  
    from /home/cabox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `eager_load!'                                                                                                                                           
    from /home/cabox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in `eager_load!'                                                                                                                                           
    from /home/cabox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/annotate-2.7.1/lib/annotate.rb:147:in `eager_load'                                                                                                                                                
    from /home/cabox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/annotate-2.7.1/bin/annotate:195:in `<top (required)>'                                                                                                                                             
    from /home/cabox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/annotate:23:in `load'                                                                                                                                                                              
    from /home/cabox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/annotate:23:in `<main>'                                                                                                                                                                            
    from /home/cabox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'                                                                                                                                                                 
    from /home/cabox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I try with `bundle exec annotate` buth i have another error.

Comment: if the answer solve your problem then let me know

Comment: Yeah,its solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `posts_controller.rb` file change:

```
params.require(:post).permit(:title, :, :body)
```

to

```
params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
```

problem is in that comma after a colon change that and re-run the command and the problem will be fixed.